# unable to get Underscore.js _groupBy working

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

This is how my JSON looks like:

```
var data=
    {
      "results": [
        {
          "ComputerName": "Computer1",
          "Date": "01/01/2014",
          "CollectionName": "Collection1",
          "MinValue": "MinVal1",
          "MaxValue": "MaxVal1",
          "AverageValue": "AvgVal1"
        },
        {
          "ComputerName": "Computer2",
          "Date": "01/01/2014",
          "CollectionName": "Collection2",
          "MinValue": "MinVal2",
          "MaxValue": "MaxVal2",
          "AverageValue": "AvgVal2"
        },
        {
          "ComputerName": "Computer1",
          "Date": "01/01/2014",
          "CollectionName": "Collection3",
          "MinValue": "MinVal3",
          "MaxValue": "MaxVal3",
          "AverageValue": "AvgVal3"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I am trying to group results by ComputerName. This is how i am doing it:

```
var computerGroup = _.groupBy(data, 'ComputerName');
```

This slices everything down to characters.

What am i doing wrong here?

--Update--

This is how the JSON comes from the controller and it says data.results is undefined.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "ComputerName": "Computer1",
      "Date": "01/01/2014",
      "CollectionName": "Collection1",
      "MinValue": "MinVal1",
      "MaxValue": "MaxVal1",
      "AverageValue": "AvgVal1"
    },
    {
      "ComputerName": "Computer2",
      "Date": "01/01/2014",
      "CollectionName": "Collection2",
      "MinValue": "MinVal2",
      "MaxValue": "MaxVal2",
      "AverageValue": "AvgVal2"
    },
    {
      "ComputerName": "Computer1",
      "Date": "01/01/2014",
      "CollectionName": "Collection3",
      "MinValue": "MinVal3",
      "MaxValue": "MaxVal3",
      "AverageValue": "AvgVal3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_.groupBy should run on the list, so use

```
var computerGroup = _.groupBy(data.results, 'ComputerName');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7ECQ/)

Comment: for some reason when 'data' comes from the controller, data.results is undefined. you know what can be wrong? i can see the JSON in my debug windows and i see results is there.

Comment: Is data defined? If so what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Do `groupBy` on data.results, not data. `groupBy` does not do a deep search of objects.

```
var computerGroup = _.groupBy(data.results, 'ComputerName');
```

[You can see my fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8sUMV/)